# How to let program wait for ajax result to continue processing?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I'm doing form validation. In the form check function, I called an ajax function to verify a field. if the return data of ajax equals "No", this function supposed to return false. However, it never wait for the ajax result return. How should I handle this issue?
my button code:

jQuery code:

```
function Checkform() {
        var result = true;
        $('input:password').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).focus();
                $(this).addClass('HighlightBorder');
                alert("Please set password.");
                result = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (!result)
            return false;
......
       $.post(rootPath + "/AjaxPages/SearchAddress.aspx", { "street": street, "city": city, "state": state, "zip": zip, "type": "DPV" }, function(data) {
            if (data == "No") {
                alert("Invalid company address, did you type in a wrong address?");
                result=false;
            } 
        });
        return result;
}
```

Then I modified my ajax code to

```
$.post(rootPath + "/AjaxPages/SearchAddress.aspx", { "street": street, "city": city, "state": state, "zip": zip, "type": "DPV" }, function(data) {
            if (data == "No") {
                alert("Invalid company address, did you type in a wrong address?");
                return false;
            } else
                return true;
```

I think this time the return value is performed after the data comes out, but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: It is an easy question to answer, but I won't unless you  format your code and put it in a code block. Click the `{}` icon in the editor.

Comment: that will learn him mike

Answer (score 1):

ajax is asynchronous, so you have to use callbacks.

```
   $.post(rootPath + "/AjaxPages/SearchAddress.aspx", { "street": street, "city": city, "state": state, "zip": zip, "type": "DPV" }, function(data) {
        if (data == "No") {
            alert("Invalid company address, did you type in a wrong address?");
            some_callback_function();//callback
        } 
    });
```

Comment: what should I write in callback function? return false?

Comment: @steven, you can't do returns in a callback.  just do what you think should be done at that point

Comment: But I have to return false if the data comes out equals "No". Otherwise, the form data will be processed by server and step into next page. Any idea?

Comment: just always `return false` and if the post goes through, submit the form (`$('#form_id').submit()`)

Comment: it's not a html page, it's an aspx page. And this part of code is in a child page embeded in a masterpage. Do you know how to set onclientclick="true" for a server button? I want to use $('#savebtn').click() function