# how to set OnClientClick to be true?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I wonder how to use jquery click a button and set it's OnClientClick to be true, so the validation process will not run. I use

```
$("[id$='btn_Save']").attr('OnClientClick', true);
     $("[id$='btn_Save']").Click();
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
ValidatorsEnabled(false); // This disables all .NET client-side validation
$("[id$='btn_Save']").Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

1: attr('OnClientClick', true) is totally wrong.

2: OnClientClick won't help you stopping to fire validation.

Set `CausesValidation="false"` for your button so it don't fire Validation.

**Edit:** What I meant is:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" CausesValidation="false" />
```

Comment: How? I tried $("[id$='btn_Save']").attr('CausesValidation', false);
            $("[id$='btn_Save']").Click(); but it doesn't work

Comment: Oh no, I have to do the validation. But somehow, I do not if a certain condition is satisfied.

Comment: I have a validation function Checkform(). This button onclientclick="return Checkform();"

Comment: Now getting a bit more idea. You can try disabling the validators from client-side something like shown here: http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/07/26/enable-disable-validator-controls-from-javascript.aspx

Comment: And where do you check that condition if to validate or not? In CheckForm??

Answer (score 0):

you mention `OnClientClick` so I'm assuming ASp.NET (you should put this as a tag).

But why will you want such thing?

```
<asp:button 
    id="btn_Save" 
    runat="server" 
    onclientclick="doSomething()" 
    text="Save" />
```

the method `doSomething` will be called and if that method return true, it will continue and do the `PostBack`.

if you want to do something before or after just add the function to the property, for example:

```
onclientclick="doThis(); doSomething();"
```

or

```
onclientclick="doSomething(); doThis();"
```

Comment: I use an ajax function to do validation, but I need to submit the form in callback function. check this link you will understand why I am seeking this function.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076455/how-to-let-program-wait-for-ajax-result-to-continue-processing

Comment: why don't you use jQUery Validation ?